# Spring boot exception handling for specific annotated methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

Our spring boot controllers have methods called by ajax as well as the standard methods rendering CRUD templates. We'd like to be able to annotate all our ajax methods with a single annotation so that regardless of what type of exception is thrown, we can return a response the ui can handle.

I've been looking at the ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler annotations, but I don't think either can be used the way we intend. ControllerAdvice can only cover entire controllers, so any exception handling would also cover the non-ajax methods. Similarly, the ExceptionHandler annotation would handle exceptions from both types of methods.

The current idea is to split the two types of methods, ajax and CRUD, into separate controllers. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is that much easy/straightforward in Spring (or at least to my current spring knowledge).

> We'd like to be able to annotate all our ajax methods with a single
>   annotation

Apart from separating ajaxMethods into another controller, I can think of another way of doing this.

1.Declare your own exception class like **myAjaxException**.

2.Don't handle this exception in controller, just throw it when you encounter any exception inside **your ajax methods**.

```
  try{
         //.... 
      }catch(Exception ex){
          throw new myAjaxException("this is myAjaxException blah blah blah");
      }
```

3.Intercept myAjaxException by implementing HandlerExceptionResolver as below.

> Any Spring bean declared in the DispatcherServlet’s application
>   context that implements **HandlerExceptionResolver** will be used to
>   **intercept** and process **any exception** raised in the MVC system and **not**
>   handled by a Controller.

```
public class AjaxExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

   public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex);
  if (ex instanceof myAjaxException) {
              //return response to UI
    }

  }
```

Comment: I considered that as well, but that would mean wrapping every ajax method in a try/catch block, which was what we are trying to avoid

Comment: I am aware of that, my solution can be another "work around" until we find better one.